# insert data form one table to other in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to do  the following to calculate customer reviews and show them  on the page:

STEP 1.
 Select data from T1  ,  count records and calculate the rating

```
SELECT COUNT(Rating) As ReviewCount, 
       ObjectID as ObID, 
       SUM(Rating)/COUNT(Rating) As ReviewScore
FROM [dbo].[Comment]
WHERE ObjectTypeID ='2' AND StatusID ='2'
GROUP BY ObjectID
```

This code works fine.

Next I want t do is insert  calculated ReviewScore value into T2

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AttributeValue] (AttributeID, Value, SortOrder)
           VALUES (5,ReviewScore, 29)
```

STEP 2
Next I want to do is get Identity  (Last inserted ID)  per each item  for example:

```
DECLARE @ID INT= @@IDENTITY
```

STEP3

I want to get the @@Identity per inserted row in STEP 2 and Insert new data:

```
------- AtribbuteID is always 5
---- ObID  is taken from the STEP 1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AttributeObjectValue]  
        ([AttributeID],[ObjectID],[Value],[AttributeValueID])
         VALUES (5,ObID,ReviewScore,@ID)
```

I am  trying to use the CTE table but cant get it to work:

```
BEGIN  TRAN

GO

;WITH CTE (ReviewCount, ObjectID, ReviewScore)

AS

(

SELECT COUNT(Rating) As ReviewCount, 
        ObjectID as ObID, 
        SUM(Rating)/COUNT(Rating) As ReviewScore
FROM [dbo].[Comment]
WHERE ObjectTypeID ='2' AND StatusID ='2'
GROUP BY ObjectID
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AttributeValue] (AttributeID, Value, SortOrder)
        VALUES (5,ReviewScore, 29)

SELECT ReviewCount FROM CTE

DECLARE @ID INT= @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AttributeObjectValue]  
      ([AttributeID],[ObjectID],[Value],[AttributeValueID])
       VALUES (5,ObID,ReviewCount,@ID)


GO

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: I agree with marc_s. Other than that, why doesn't it work? What happens? Do you receive an error message? Do you get the wrong results?

Comment: Why do you need to use CTE? Your CTE `SELECT` statement `SELECT ReviewCount FROM CTE`, is not going to work since you are doing an `INSERT` right after the CTE structure. The CTE is only available within the same statement that it is created.

Comment: It's seemed that you can use [`OUTPUT INSERTED` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) in your `INSERT` statement.